# R: Error in sort.list(bx[m$xi]) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list' Have you called 'sort' on a list? Merge data frames error

Tags: r, merge, nested-lists

I have two data frames I would like to merge. The data frames look like this:

```
> head(tk1_h)
    userId                  hobbies
1 102802401691 566588ca00016a4e470bb345
2 102802401691 566588ca00016a4e470bb34c
3 102802401691 575949efb3e4c06ffd5384e1
4 102802401691 55b3cd55ef481d737db42084
5 102802401691 566588ca00016a4e470bb350
6 102802401691 566588ca00016a4e470bb34c
```

and

```
> head(tags)
          _id              type     content
1 55a9098ad77b192554c38d50 feed adok-veszek
2 55a909a4d77b192554c38d51 feed keres-kínál
3 55a909dad77b192554c38d52 feed   jó-helyek
4 55a909e6d77b192554c38d53 feed     oktatás
5 55a909ebd77b192554c38d54 feed     program
6 55a909f0d77b192554c38d55 feed       sport
```

Here, "hobbies" and "_id" are identical so by merging the two data frames I will see which user has which hobbies (<-- content from df tags). I used the following code:

```
tk1_h2 <- merge.data.frame(tk1_h, tags, by.x = "profile", by.y = "_id")
```

by.x = "profile" because tk1_h dataframe is nested and looks like this:

```
> str(tk1_h)
'data.frame':   27716 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ userId : num  1.03e+11 1.03e+11 1.03e+11 1.03e+11 1.03e+11 ...
 $ profile:'data.frame':    27716 obs. of  1 variable:
 ..$ hobbies: chr  "566588ca00016a4e470bb345" "566588ca00016a4e470bb34c" 
 "575949efb3e4c06ffd5384e1" "55b3cd55ef481d737db42084" ...
```

Merging the two dataframes returns this error:

```
 Error in sort.list(bx[m$xi]) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
 Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

I have seen other stack overflow posts about this issue, but unlist() didn't help me out.
How can I code merging the two data frames correctly?
Thank you!

Comment: Please include a `dput` of your sample data.

Comment: Look at `str(tk1_h)`: $profile is a dataframe!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, the problem is that you have a nested dataframe. I can't think of any solution except unlisting the nested dataframe (converting it to a vector):

```
tk1_h$profile <- unlist(tk1_h$profile)
```

Comment: Yes this worked, thank you! For some reason when I was doing it it didn't work before, but now it did

Comment: Glad I could help!!